# delete position in array of string

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

hello i'm new in Java and i'm having a trouble.

My program prints Strings in a Jframe. I generate a array of Strings called v. v[0] is always null. And I request an input from the user to delete one position of the array v, wich i call numberdel. If I have an array

> v[0]=[null] v[1]=[hello] v[2]=[my name is] v[3]=[john] and if
>   numberdel=2

the final result should be

> v[0]=[null] v[1]=[hello] v[2]=[john]

I wasn't making it so I created a new array called b. But it still isn't working like a wanted...

```
public static
(...)

String[] b = new String[v.length-1];

boolean jump = false;

for(int j=1; j<b.length; j++){
    if(jump==false){
        if(j != numberdel){
            b[j] = v[j];
        }
        else jump = true;
    }
    else{
        b[j] = v[j+1];
    }
    (...)//action for every cycle
}
(...)
```

Comment: simply you can do something like this...in single array just swap the numberdel with numberdel+1 th value and set numberdel+1 to null...but once you swap them you have to swap the next values also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `j == numberdel`, your loop will set `jump` to `true` and skip right past the `else` statement.

I'd recommend not using the `jump` variable since it will basically be false when `j < numberdel` and true otherwise.

```
for(int j = 1; j < b.length; j++)
{
    if (j < numberdel)
        b[j] = v[j];
    else
        b[j] = v[j + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do your task in the single array itself...as below...

```
void delet(int numberdel)
{
     for(int i=numberdel ; i< v.length ;i++)
        v[i] = v[i+1];

}
```

i suggest that if you can do the same thing in one array then why to waste space...you are doing the thing its fine,but i guess this is better...hope it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.arrayCopy` starting with array `v`. `numberdel` is the 0-based item to delete.

```
String[] b = new String[v.length-1];

System.arrayCopy(v, 0, b, 0, numberdel);
System.arrayCopy(v, numberdel + 1, b, numberdel, v.length - numberdel);
```